# How can I read the lines on my code without including spaces? C#

Tags: c#

```
int cont1 = 0;
string[] LOC = this.txtCodigo.Text.Split('\n');
foreach (var item in LOC)
{
    if (item != "\r")
    { 
        cont1++; 
    }
}
```

So I have this. If I could get a better answer than this that would help, because it's not working!

Comment: Better how? It's not really clear what you're asking for. You seem to be just counting the lines... (You could do the counting more easily as `int count = txtCodigo.Text.Split('\n').Count(x => x != "\r");`)

Comment: Split has a second parameter that allows you to remove empty lines. _StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries_

Comment: or if you mean literal spaces, you should use string.Replace or string.Trim

Comment: It would be helpful if you stayed here to reply to the comments trying to help you instead of posting your question then leaving. As it is right now your question will be closed because it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to count the lines, clases and methods from a simple project, but when it's counting lines, I don't it to count "\r". 
Have it show only the lines with actual characters in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of splitting just on the `\n` character you can use the Split overload that allows to split on more than one string and, if some empty lines are produced, ask Split to remove them

```
string[] LOC = this.txtCodigo.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

At this point your LOC array doesn't contains any `\r` to skip and you can get the count just from the LOC.Length property

```
count1 = LOC.Length;
```

Comment: I go one better - instead of "\r", "\n" use the Environment.NewLine static string. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, using Linq

```
txtCodigo.Text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).Count(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
```